# Users with Contribute permission level can share site/documents

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SP 2013,and we have bunch of users in the members group.
We noticed they can share the site or documents.

Why?

Can i disable that?

I dont want people with contribute permission to be able to share anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis,

You can use following CodePlex project to completely disable Share, Follow options from Document Library:
https://removesharefollow.codeplex.com/

This should also help
http://www.eliostruyf.com/hiding-the-social-actions-follow-share-from-the-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2013/

Its not really an answer to the question.. Because I think it should be doable by setting some permissions, but I couldn't figure out what permissions need to revoke.. maybe someone else can give us the direction

Comment: lol, Elio is sitting next to me.! great article.!

Comment: @LuisValenciaMunoz co-incidence :)